# Prestashop 1.6.1 login via url parameters

Tags: api, authentication, url, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to integrate a prestashop 1.6.1 online shop with the Delphi PunchOut catalog. 
However when the user visits our catalog he needs to be automatically authenticated via parameters passed into the url.

The question is if Prestashop has such thing as an url based authentication, where you keep the user logged in if he either has the right username and pass, or username and hashed password, or token, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I'd advice you to upgrade to Prestashop 1.7. This version works with the Symfony Framework, and with this framework you can easily build this. And besides that PS 1.6 is not being updated anymore.

Comment: Thanks, i was aware of that. Unfortunately the upgrade is yet to come. Not everything goes smoothly due to the heavy between in the versions.